# to configure Active Record with an environment variable DATABASE_URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am very new to ROR, I have a question on How to configure Active Record with an environment variable **DATABASE_URL**. If configure this don't need to keep the values in database.yml? Is this option available only in production or can achieve this in Development environment too?

Thank you

Comment: Refer this link [stack overflow][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26886109/to-configure-active-record-with-an-environment-variable-database-url#

Comment: Thanks pulkit21. It's useful info.

Comment: @rubymerite If the info is helpful please give a upvote thanks

Comment: I have reputation count = 1. I can't vote to anything at this moment. I am sorry.

Answer (score 0):

In your config yml file, you can declare environment for set of variables:

Eg. in database.yml

```
development:
  adapter: mysql
  encoding: utf8
  database: dev
  username: root
  password: password
  socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
  backup: /home/usr/databackup
test:
  adapter: mysql
  encoding: utf8
  database: test
  username: root
  password: password
  socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
production:
  adapter: mysql
  encoding: utf8
  database: prod
  username: root
  password: password
  socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

Once declaring variables like this you will get different values for `ENV['DATABASE_URL']` in different environments (as per declared values).

Answer (score 0):

My `config/database.yml` has a:

```
production:
  url: <%= ENV['DATABASE_URL'] %>
```

And as an environment variable on the server that I put on `/etc/profile.d/user.sh` file, this one:

```
export RAILS_ENV=production
export DATABASE_URL=postgres://user:password@localhost/db_name
export SECRET_KEY_BASE=df577_etc_etc_etc_etc_9a6da0
```